# What edit did you made here on Buddhism SE?

Tags: discussion, meta

If you like to get some feedback of your generous work in editing questions and answers, to improve your work and tho have some feedback, just post the link of your edit and maybe some comments.

**Why you should answer this question not only now but often?**

- to keep meta discussions in regard of improvements away from the main topic
- to encourage you and others to make improvements and edits
- to have at least good quality of questions and answers
- to improve your work
- to give a possibility for others to honor your work
- to have a place to get feedback of what you have done and do
- to let you know that good deeds have good fruits if not sure about that
- to give also moderators a good amount of feedback in regard of edits and there approve.

---

To make it possible to give such as reputation for edits or certain feedbacks to them and comming form the question "[is-there-a-way-to-give-a-acknowledgement-reputation-for-an-edit](http://%20https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1884/is-there-a-way-to-give-a-acknowledgement-reputation-for-an-edit)" Atma thought to give this way aside of the software functions a change.

Just a link or what ever you like to mention in regard of your executed edit is a fine placed.

It gives also space for finer feedback. Try to answer!

Comment: I think that any [upvotes on meta-topics](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250889/49942) have no effect on "reputation".

Comment: It should be no problem to simply put it into the main place, if such is wished. At least it should give just a sample even if adoptable. On the other hand, its maybe quite good to have it without "earning of reputation" effects, as a answering here could be otherwise seen as "Hey, give me some reputations", which could be the only reason for misuse. Of course Atma is not so talented in introduce it in a pleasant way, but guesses that such use would have good generally effects if used often. And server and editor is naturally normal no person who likes to earn visible reputations.

Answer (score 2):

Atma made an addition here yesterday, not sure if right and proper.

https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/7306/7500

Comment: It was fine, a good edit. It started as a suggested edit and was [approved by moderator (Lanka)](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/3694). Also each time you edit a topic it moves to the top of the [active view](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active), so probably several people review each edit.

Comment: The reference was to a page of sangham.net whose topic is Sister Uppalavanna? When you give a reference for a quote, it might be more normal to reference the page (web site or book) on which you found the quoted text (written by Sister Uppalavanna).

Comment: There is a download link of Ven Sitsters given work in this tread for those who are interested: http://sangham.net/index.php?action=tpmod;dl=get136. Atma did not like to stress it, since it is not known if such is really good. Atma did not fine time to actually present them, only some are already online avaliable. AN1-AN4: here http://sangham.net/index.php/page,AN-en.html

Answer (score 1):

You can review the list of edits which anyone has made, by looking at the their user profile.

1. Select the user's profile
2. Choose the "Activity" tab
3. Select "All actions" and then "Revisions"

For example, the edits I made are listed here: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/254/chrisw?tab=activity&sort=revisions

Comment: Atma is not allowed to edit your post here. So just as sample ChrisWs answer would be: [http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/13334/7500](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/13334/7500)

Comment: Could check it and vote, up and down. And do so now.

Answer (score 1):

Atma made an edit, since the context was not clear of where the answer and the quotes in it where originated

https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/13366/7500